# Keras LSTM: Injecting already-known *future* values into prediction

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I've built an LSTM In Keras with the goal of predicting future values of a time-series from a high-dimensional, time-index input.

However, there's a unique requirement: for certain time points in the future, we know with certainty what some values of the input series will be. For example:

```
model = SomeLSTM()
trained_model = model.train(train_data)
known_data = [(24, {feature: 2, val: 7.0}), (25, {feature: 2, val: 8.0})]
predictions = trained_model(look_ahead=48, known_data=known_data)
```

Which would train the model up to time `t` (the end of training), and predict forward `48` time periods from time `t`, but substituting `known_data` values for `feature` 2 at times `24` and `25`.

How exactly can I explicitly inject this into the LSTM at some time?

For reference, here's the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(hidden, input_shape=(look_back, num_features)))
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Dense(look_ahead))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
```

This may be a result of my un-intuitive grasp of LSTMs, and I'd appreciate any clarification. I've dived into the Keras source code, and my first guess is to inject it right into the LSTM `state` variable, but I'm unsure how to do that at time `t` (or even if that is correct.)

Comment: Are these known times the same for all sequences? (Always 24 and 25, for instance?)

Comment: that's going to be really difficult to solve using the LSTM in Keras. You might need to switch to a stateful LSTM and manually feed the timesteps through.

Comment: @Daniel - Unfortunately not; they can change depending on the state of knowledge.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut - hmm, thanks. Do you have a suggestion for a good framework for doing that (ideally in Python)?

Comment: How about simple make full predictions and changing only known values to the known numbers?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko what do you mean by that? Do you mean using the LSTM to predict each feature forward?

Comment: You first predict all values using LSTM and than in predicted sequence - you could simply change rhe values you know.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko would that require training the LSTM `num_features` times? Is there an inherent component of a singularly-trained LSTM that can do do that in one step?

Comment: You could easily apply that as a postprocessing step.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko thank you for your help and pardon my ignorance! Do you mean train the LSTM with outcome Y and then predict `X_n`? Surely, it wouldn't capture the relationships if it hadn't been trained with `X_n` as an output variable? Or do you mean training just 1-dimensional temporal LSTMs to predict `X_n` forward? Many thanks for your help & patience!

Answer (score 0):

I think a *clean* way of doing this is to introduce `2*look_ahead` new features, where for each `0 <= i < look_ahead` `2*i`-th feature is an indicator whether the value of the `i`-th time step is known and `(2*i+1)`-th is the value itself (0 if not known). Accordingly, you can generate training data with these features to make your model take into account these known values.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but maybe create your own layer to go at the end that sets the data to the known values, similar to how dropout sets random values to zero. As a side note, I have had better results with pooling than dropout, so maybe try switching that out and training it. Here is a good guide on how to do it. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/keras/keras_customized_layer.htm